# Merge sql queries

Tags: sql, select

I want to make this code in just only one statement, but I need in 4 different column.

```
SELECT a017tkahwin AS klaki FROM a017 WHERE a017tkahwin='K' AND a017kjantina='L'
SELECT a017tkahwin AS blaki FROM a017 WHERE a017tkahwin='B' AND a017kjantina='L'
SELECT a017tkahwin AS kpuan FROM a017 WHERE a017tkahwin='K' AND a017kjantina='P'
SELECT a017tkahwin AS bpuan FROM a017 WHERE a017tkahwin='B' AND a017kjantina='P'
```

Comment: what sort of sql, which engine?

Comment: Your question doesnt make any sense. What if one statement returns more rows? Even if all of them did return same number of rows, on what basis would you  combine them in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try something like this :

```
select (SELECT a017tkahwin FROM a017 WHERE a017tkahwin='K' AND 
a017kjantina='L') as klaki , ( SELECT a017tkahwin  FROM a017 WHERE 
a017tkahwin='B' AND a017kjantina='L' ) AS blaki , (SELECT a017tkahwin  FROM 
a017 WHERE a017tkahwin='K' AND a017kjantina='P' ) AS kpuan , (SELECT 
a017tkahwin  FROM a017 WHERE a017tkahwin='B' AND a017kjantina='P') AS bpuan
```

for oracle DB , you need to add from dual in the end.

Answer (score -1):

for sql-server2012+ using IIF otherwise use CASE

```
SELECT 
  iif(a017tkahwin = 'K' and a017kjantina = 'L',a017tkahwin,null)  AS klaki,
  iif(a017tkahwin = 'B' and a017kjantina = 'L',a017tkahwin,null)  AS blaki,
  iif(a017tkahwin = 'K' and a017kjantina = 'P',a017tkahwin,null)  AS kpuan,
  iif(a017tkahwin = 'B' and a017kjantina = 'P',a017tkahwin,null)  AS bpuan
 FROM a017 WHERE a017tkahwin IN ('K','B') AND a017kjantina in ('L','P')
```